# Entity Framework date only property format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date

I am using Entity Framework Core to create a simple user table that contains a birthday column.

```
    [Column(TypeName="Date")]
    [Display(Name = "Data de nascimento")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

Then it successfuly show me only the date on the Details page and not the time, but when I try to edit the user, the input box asks me for a DateTime and not only date.

Comment: Can you please share the input and the error please?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's picking the wrong editor template. Try adding the `DataType` attribute to the property:

```cs
[Column(TypeName="Date")]
[Display(Name = "Data de nascimento")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

[DataTypeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute)
[DataType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype)